# Git tags remain in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, git-tag

I would like to delete all Git tags for my project, which I did using `git tag -d` for local tags and then I pushed that to `origin`, so the tags in `origin` are deleted as well.

Indeed, if I run `git tag -l` or `git ls-remote --tags origin` then no tag is displayed.

However, my build is set up such that whenever I push, a build is triggered in Jenkins. When the build is triggered on the machine running Jenkins, `git tag -l` does show several tags.

How can I delete those tags?

Answer (score 6):

Another solution that helped me is to configure Jenkins temporarily to wipe out repository and make a force clone:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the end I went to `${JENKINS_HOME}/.jenkins/workspace` and I deleted all the folders containing Jenkins builds for the Git branch that I'm on.

That solved the issue.

Probably the `.git` repository was copied over from previous builds or something like that.

Comment: You can instruct the Jenkins job to delete the workspace. That would get rid of the left over files as well.